# Focus is lost if validation fails on onblur event

Tags: jsf, focus, richfaces, onblur, ajax4jsf

I use JSF 1.2.
I process onblur event with aj4:support and actionListener

```
<a4j:support event="onblur" reRender="panel1"  
      actionListener="#{bean.changeData}"  />
```

ActionListener validates inputted data. I would like focus to be returned if validation fails.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set focus="componentId" in a4j:support.